# sql multiple columns plus sum of each column

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL, I am counting the occurrence of several events (fields) over a time span of years. I then display this in columns by year.  My query works perfect when grouped by year. I now want to add a final column which displays the aggregate of the years.  How do I include the **total of columns** query?

```
Event 2008  2009  2010  2011 total  
  A     0     2    0     1     3  
  B     1     2    3     0     6  
etc.
```

Here is the real query:

```
select   
    count(*) as total_docs,  
    YEAR(field_document_date_value) as doc_year,  
    field_document_facility_id_value as facility,  
    IF(count(IF(field_document_type_value ='LIC809',1, NULL)) >0,count(IF(field_document_type_value ='LIC809',1, NULL)),'-') as doc_type_LIC809,  
    IF(count(IF(field_document_type_value ='LIC9099',1, NULL)) >0,count(IF(field_document_type_value ='LIC9099',1, NULL)),'-') as doc_type_LIC9099,  
    IF(count(field_document_f1_value) >0,count(field_document_f1_value),'-')  as substantial_compliance,  
    IF(count(field_document_f2_value) >0,count(field_document_f2_value),'-') as deficiencies_sited,  
    IF(count(field_document_f3_value) >0,count(field_document_f3_value),'-') as admin_outcome_809,  
    IF(count(field_document_f4_value) >0,count(field_document_f4_value),'-') as unfounded,  
    IF(count(field_document_f5_value) >0,count(field_document_f5_value),'-') as substantiated,  
    IF(count(field_document_f6_value) >0,count(field_document_f6_value),'-') as inconclusive,  
    IF(count(field_document_f7_value) >0,count(field_document_f7_value),'-') as further_investigation,  
    IF(count(field_document_f8_value) >0,count(field_document_f8_value),'-') as admin_outcome_9099,  
    IF(count(field_document_type_a_value) >0,count(field_document_type_a_value),'-') as penalty_type_a,  
    IF(count(field_document_type_b_value) >0,count(field_document_type_b_value),'-') as penalty_type_b,  
    IF(sum(field_document_civil_penalties_value) >0,CONCAT('$',sum(field_document_civil_penalties_value)),'-') as total_penalties,  
    IF(count(field_document_noncompliance_value) >0,count(field_document_noncompliance_value),'-') as total_noncompliance  

from rcfe_content_type_facility_document  

where YEAR(field_document_date_value) BETWEEN year(NOW()) -9 AND year(NOW())  
  and field_document_facility_id_value = :facility  

group by doc_year
```

Comment: I just tried to include my query but don't think it took.  How do I get the query to you?

Comment: You can just edit it into your question, don't worry about formatting - someone can help you fix it up.

Comment: Edit your question and insert query into it with **code** tags

Comment: I can't get the relation between your query and your small example :s Can you clarify it please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not `GROUP` row twice in a `SELECT`, so you can only count row in a year or in total. You can `UNION` two `SELECT` (one grouped by year, second not grouped - total) to overcome this limitation, but I think it is better to count total from year result in script if there is any.

Simplified example:

```
SELECT by_year.amount, years.date_year FROM

-- generating years pseudo table
(
    SELECT 2008 AS date_year 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2009 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2010 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2011
) AS years

-- joining with yearly stat data
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT SUM(value_field) AS amount, YEAR(date_field) AS date_year FROM data
    GROUP BY YEAR(date_field)
) AS by_year USING(date_year)

-- appending total
UNION ALL SELECT SUM(value_field) AS amount, 'total' AS date_year FROM data
```

Comment: Thank you - the UNION works.  Unfortunately I don't have access to script.  My other problem is that some years do not have data thus they do not return any values.  I need to figure out a way to show those "vacant" years.  I can't seem to grasp how to do this using a LEFT OUTER JOIN which should do the trick.

Comment: Added example with empty years

Comment: Also, vearutop, thank you for the clarification to show years that do not have any values.  It worked perfectly.  You Rock!!!

Answer (score 0):

**WITH ROLLUP** is your friend:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Use your original query and simply add this to the last line:

```
GROUP BY doc_year WITH ROLLUP
```

That will add a final cumulative row to your query's result set.